# Building own custom backend server in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am about to make my E-Commerce project on nextjs, have been looking into the docs of it but I have some questions which remains unanswered / unclear as this one will be my first nextjs project.

Stating them below in points so that it's clear as to what I want to know

> 1. I see we can add server code along with nextjs app inside server folder in our application, but as i have my backend ready already in
>    different space,  so it ok to link my nextjs app to different backend
>    server (just as we do in a typical Reactjs project)?
> 2. If i can add a different backend server to nextjs app, is there any cons of it ?
> 3. Will the production setup become complex to serv my nextjs app while going in production level?
> 4. Will it cause any issue in overall speed of my app ?

All views are appreciated :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, its okay, and it's recommend to use Next.js as a headless
   frontend with a shopify, big commerce etc backend - check out [Next
   commerce template](https://nextjs.org/commerce).  There are also BigCommerce and Shopify integrations in the [Vercel marketplace](https://vercel.com/blog/integrations-marketplace).
2. No cons - standard practice
3. Server side rendering in Next.js can be complex - this [Terraform regrestiry](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/dealmore/next-js/aws/latest) shows a pretty good picture of what's required.  But Vercel obvsoully recommendeds hosting on thier [vercel](https://vercel.com/) platform, I believe [AWS Amplify](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/host-a-next-js-ssr-app-with-real-time-data-on-aws-amplify/) also partially supports Next.
4. If done correctly, no - Your frontend can only be as fast as your backend, if you backend is fast then your frontend will have the opportunity to be fast as well.

Comment: thanks man, i think i am clear now :)